# sed not working as intended in bash script

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to replace some strings in a file with sed and I'm getting a strange error.

Here is the script...

```
#!/bin/bash

TEMPLATE=/etc/nginx/site-template

if [ -f $TEMPLATE ]; then
        echo -n
else
        echo "Template $TEMPLATE not found."
        exit
fi

function usagehelp {
        echo "Usage: DOMAIN SITEDIR"
        echo "Example: createsite.sh test.com /var/www/sites/site" 
}

if [ -z $1 ]; then
        usagehelp
        exit
fi

if [ -z $2 ]; then
        usagehelp
        exit
fi

SDOMAIN=$1
SDIR=$2

if [ -f /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/$SDOMAIN ]; then
        echo "Site already exists!"
        exit
fi 

SCONFIG=/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/$SDOMAIN

cp $TEMPLATE $SCONFIG

sed -i -e "s/%DOMAIN%/$SDOMAIN/g" $SCONFIG
sed -i -e "s/%SITEDIR%/$SDIR/g" $SCONFIG

mkdir $SDIR
chown john:www-data $SDIR
chmod a-rwx,u+rwx,g+rx $SDIR

if nginx -t; then
        nginx -s reload
        echo "nginx reloaded with new site"
fi
```

Running it produces the following output, and I'm not quite sure why. I really need an extra set of eyes...

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unknown option to `s'
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
nginx reloaded with new site
```

Comment: In the future, it'd be nice to trim everything but the minimum needed to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: What are `%DOMAIN%` and `%SITEDIR%`? Are these supposed to be environment variables? The `%` notation looks specific to Windows.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use uppercase variable names, as those are usually environment variables, and you risk overwriting them.

Comment: I chose the percentage signs for the variables in a nginx config template I wanted to change for minimal possibility they'll conflict with nginx's own syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of `%SITEDIR%`, if your `$SDIR` contains a directory name, then the first `/` in the name will be seen as the end of the `s///` command, rather than as data.

The bad answer is to try to pick a sigil which won't likely be in the filename -- for instance, if you don't expect the `@` sign to be in a filename, use:

```
sed -i -e "s@%SITEDIR%@$SDIR@g"
```

The good answer is to use a completely different tool -- awk, perl, etc. There's an awk script which does this safely in [BashFAQ #21](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021).

Comment: +1, but there IS a way to make the `sed` command more robust: escape the `/` chars. in the replacement string with `\ `, using bash's parameter (variable) subsitution; e.g. `SDOMAIN=/ab/cde; sed -e "s/%DOMAIN%/${SDOMAIN//\//\\/}/g" <<<$'Domain: %DOMAIN%.'`